# HashMap value auto increment

Tags: java, hashmap

when I was coding, one question occurred to me, **which is if the value part(Integer) in the HashMap is able to auto-increment in the following scenario?**

```
Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    
dictionary.put("a",1);
dictionary.put("b",1);
```

Comment: using a `for loop` is not really an option?

Comment: @Mahan  I just wanna to know if the value 1 will be added to 2 automatically... that's just a simple example

Comment: It is not good api design.  You can always increment and put into map.

Comment: @Jayan yes, I know that, I just use the simple example to express my question that if the value 1 to be added to 2 automatically.

Comment: @ Ivy : I see. You need to come with a custom wrapper on top of map.

Comment: If you're just using a count, you don't need a HashMap, you can use a List or Set. I would only use a HashMap if you need constant lookup time and there can be duplicates in your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```java
Map<Key, AtomicInteger> dictionary =
  new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

dictionary.get(key).incrementAndGet();
```

Also consider using a `for` loop to simplify the code.

Comment: If the key is added for the first time, dictionary.get(key) returns null.

Comment: @Timmy, yes of course, AtomicInteger need to be instantiated with new AtomicInteger()

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) framework which is open sourced by Google.

Using Multiset can greatly simplify your life.

```
    Multiset<String> set = HashMultiset.create();
    set.add("abc"):
    set.add("acd");
    set.add("abc");

    // use set.count(Object) to get the counter of the object
    int c = set.count("abc");

    // or iterate through the set to get each object and its count
    for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : set.entrySet()){
         String str = entry.getElement();
         int count = entry.getCount();
    }
```

Compare to the traditional way that uses ordinary HashMaps:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void add(String str){
        Integer oldValue = map.get(str);
        if (oldValue == null){
            map.put(str, 1);
        } else{
            map.put(str, oldValue + 1);
        }
    }
```

Even if you use mutable counters as the value of the HashMap, the code is still very cumbersome.

```
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

    public void add(String str){
        AtomicInteger counter = map.get(str);
        if (counter == null){
            counter = new AtomicInteger();
            map.put(str, counter);
        }
        counter.incrementAndGet();
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom class `AutoIncrementHashMap` which internally uses a `HashMap`, have an auto incrementing variable `count` and a `put(String)` method which adds a `String` member and increments the `counter` every time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and fastest solution is to use [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html)

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> map = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();

public void add(String str){
    map.adjustOrPutValue(str, 1, 1);
}
```

Trove support primitives in collections making them more efficient, and in this case has a method which does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a support class:

```
public class HashMapInteger<K> extends HashMap<K,Integer> {  
          public void increment(K key) {
            if(super.containsKey(key))
                super.put(key,super.get(key)+1);
            else
                super.put(key,new Integer(1));
          }

          public void increment(K key, int val) {
                if(super.containsKey(key))
                    super.put(key,super.get(key)+val);
                else
                    super.put(key,new Integer(val));
              }
        }
```

To use it:

```
HashMapInteger<String> map = new HashMapInteger<String>();
map.increment("abc");
map.increment("abc");
System.out.println(map.get("abc"));//Output is 2
```